# Remote other server via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, linux, windows, apache

i have two server,

- A : webserver
- B : DNS server

i have following code and i put in Server A,

```
<?php $submit = $_POST['submit'];
if($submit == "Restart") {
if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't
exist");
if(!($con = ssh2_connect("x.x.x.x", 22))){
echo "fail: unable to establish connection\n";
} else {
if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, "user", "password")) {
    echo "fail: unable to authenticate\n";
} else {
    // allright, we're in!
    echo "OK: logged in...end Restart\n";

    // execute a command
    if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, "service bind9 restart" ))) {
        echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
    } else {
        // collect returning data from command
        stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
        $data = "";
        while ($buf = fread($stream,4096)) {
            $data .= $buf;
        }
        fclose($stream);
        echo "<pre>";
        echo $data; //Prints the output
        echo "</pre>"; 
        } 
      } 
    } 
  } echo '<form action="" method="post"
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Restart"></form>';
  ?>
```

The problem is , when i execute the code from server A, 
server B dont want restart.
But when i change code command like " dmesg , ifconfig, whoami " the code is work , i just want restart service bind9 
can we do this simulation..
thanks for help

Comment: *i just want restart service bind9* you need sudo rights to reastart service bind9 and i bet, apache/php user is not allowed to do that ... google for bash scripts and SUID BIT .. and i pray you know what you want to do

Comment: not sure why too... I have this problem too, ended making a bash script and run the bash script

Comment: Look at /var/log/syslog when starting bind up and see if it spits any specific errors out that lead you to the problem (tail -f /var/log/syslog).

Comment: donal123 hahaha.. thanks for pray me,  all @ thanks for your advice

Comment: Thanks all, case is solved, iam just change to root and script now is work